# Standards for hiring trusted personnel - American or Canadian Government?

Tags: corporate-policy, people-management, government

Is anyone familiar with an ISO standard outlining the hiring of labour for vendors being hired by DHS or Canadian government? I've found security standards but nothing for hiring practices.

*Edit for clarification.* Our company will be selling to the public sector for city engineering and emergency services. Since we're providing applications, we'll need to conform to standards for security. We've been able to find standards for software security, but nothing explaining labour practices (minimum pay, background checks, repeated background checks). I estimate it will take some research to find this information so if anyone has previous experience I'd be grateful to hear the insight. Thanks :)

Comment: I think if you spell labor, *"labour"*, you're automatically disqualified ;)

Comment: @DeLonge - The question looks pretty vague to me.  Care to specify what you're after?

Comment: @AviD LOL I moved to Canada and adopted "English" spelling. But unfortunately for you a third of the world spells it that way ;)

Comment: @Iszi I am making an edit to clarify.

Comment: @DeLonge I'm not sure ISO would concern themselves with hiring policies for national governments.

Comment: @Graham I agree it's a diverse and dynamic issue. I'll try to find who the best organization is for such standards/accreditation.

Comment: How could there be an ISO standard for hiring for at DHS? Doesn't ISO stand for International Standards Organization? If the ISO is prescribing who DHS hires, then I want an entirely new DHS.

And last I checked, Canada was laboring under the impression that they got to make their own laws without resort to either US or ISO. If the Canadian parliament has been replaced by the ISO, then someone is drawing a salary they don't deserve.

Answer (score 2):

Common Criteria is a system level standard used by both counties (along with many others depending on the accreditation plan) but that does not address your question.  If the issue is related to hiring foreign coders there may be a problem if the project touches International Traffic in Arms Regulations (ITAR) and Export Administration Regulations controls in the US.  This PDF may help http://www.bis.doc.gov/seminarsandtraining/training-modules/essentials_of_export_controls_modules_1_6.pdf   The technology used, if controlled, could present an issue even if the product is not for export as the knowledge is controlled from export as well.

Comment: Interesting I appreciate the link. If I find any specific criteria that answers the question I will also post it here. It's a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Within the USA, the Department of Labor exists to provide that information. Of course there are additional tiers of laws at the state level, but the Department of Labor will be happy to tell you about minimum pay, etc.  It is, quite literally, their *raison d'etre*.

With respect to background checks, I'm not entirely sure at the local/city level, but I suspect you'll find that the common denominator is either the Public Trust Clearance or the background check required for the [HSPD-12 credential](http://www.dhs.gov/homeland-security-presidential-directive-12) ( I think that is a NACI today but will change in the near future).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_clearance) is a fairly good place to start for both countries.  Figure out the credentials required, and that should tell you what identity vetting and background investigation is required.